# JavaScript RegEx Fails In IE / Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've run into an issue of regex match not evaluating in Internet Explorer and in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome and Opera. I know Chrome is generally much more tolerant of mistakes so I suspect I've dropped the ball somewhere along the way - yet none of the online evaluation tools seem to find any errors in my expression. I'm sorry that it's such a convoluted expression but hopefully something will be easily obvious as the culprit. The expression is as follows:

```
keyData = data.match(/\w+\u0009\w+\u0009[\u0009]?\w+\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?(\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?)?(\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?)?(\u0009([-]?\w+|%%)[@]?)?\u0009\u0009\/\//g);
```

'data' is a text file which I am parsing with no errors. I wont post the whole file here but what I am hoping to match is something such as the following:

```
10  Q       1   0439    0419    -1      // CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SHORT I, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SHORT I, <none>
```

I believe that when I post the string here it removes the 'u0009' characters so if you'd like to see one of the full files, I've linked one [here](http://seanmcquay.com/language/belarusian.klc). If there is anything more I can clarify, please let me know!

**Edit:**
My goal in this post is understanding not only why this is failing, but also if this expression well-formatted. 
After further review, it seems that it's an issue with how Internet Explorer and Firefox parse the text file. They seem to strip out the tabs and replace them with spaces. I tried to update the expression and it matches with no problems in an online validator but it still fails in IE/FF.

**Edit 2**
I have since updated my expression to a clearer form taking into account feedback. The issue still is persisting in IE and Firefox. It seems to be an issue with the string itself. IE won't let me match more than a single character, no matter what my expression is. For example, if the character string of the file is `KEYBOARD` and I try to match with `/\w+/`, it will just return `K`.

```
/[0-9](\w)?(\t+|\s+)\w+(\t+|\s+)[0-9](\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?(\t+|\s+)\/\//g
```

Comment: I was using `\u0009` originally because I didn't realize that \it was equivalent to `\t`. More specifically, when developing my expression I was checking the characters in the text file and it wasn't a standard space so I checked the unicode character and  it said `\u0009` so I went with it. It's much more compact to go with `\t`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: F.Y.I. the `(\t+|\s+)` is redundant, since `\s` incorporates `\t`. And `[0-9]` could be simplified to `\d`. So `\d(\w)?(\s+)\w+(\s+)\d(\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)((\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?(\s+)\/\/` is a *somewhat* simplified version.

Comment: Also, are the capture groups really intended? They capture fragments and space mostly.

Comment: Ah! That looks even better. I didn't realize `\s` handled `\t` but that does make sense. Handy to remember. I'm not sure what you mean by the capture groups - I'm using this expression as an overall match so if the groups return bits, they all sum up to a complete match, correct?

Answer (score 0):

After poking around with my regex for a while, I suspected something was wrong with the way IE was actually reading the text file as compared to Chrome. Specifically, if I had the string `KEYBOARD`within the text file and I tried to match it using `/\w+/`, it would simply return `K` in IE but in Chrome it would match the whole string `KEYBOARD`. I suspected IE was inserting some dead space between characters so I stepped through the first few characters of the file and printed their unicode equivalent.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    console.log(data.charCodeAt(i) + ' ' + data[i]);
}
```

This confirmed my suspicion and I saw `u0000` pop up between each character. I'm not sure why there are NULL characters between each character but to resolve my issue I simply performed:
    data = data.replace(/\u0000+/g, '');
This completely resolved my issue and I was able to parse my string like normal using the expression:

```
keyData = data.match(/[0-9](\w)?(\t+|\s+)\w+(\t+|\s+)[0-9](\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)(\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%)((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?((\t+|\s+)(-1|\w+@?|%%))?(\t+|\s+)\/\//g);
```

Comment: Could it be that the file is UTF-16 and you're reading as ASCII or UTF-8? That would explain it.

Comment: Downloaded the linked file and that confirms that it's UTF-16 (or UCS-2) so the question is, how do you *read* it?

Comment: I'm reading the file with the simplified AJAX get command `$.get('file.klc', function(data) { });`. I guess I should have checked encoding since it's an export from another program. Are you saying that how's it's encoding on the server side causes this issue or is it how it is encoded after being read?